# Why can't I use 'then()' with redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I followed redux toolkit docs here to use 'then()'.
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results

and I wrote exactly the same codes in my app.
and I get `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error.
I tried other ways to achieve it, include using `.unwrap()` (I got unwrap of undefined error),
 async-await (I got 'meta' of undefined) etc..
but all of them failed.
What I did wrong?

- action.js

```js
import axios from '@/axios';
import {BASEURL} from '@/App';
import {authToken} from '@/service/auth/auth.service';
import {createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk('users/fetchByIdStatus', async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
  let response = await axios.get(`${BASEURL}/test/`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authToken(),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
  return response.data;
});
```

- reducer

```js
import {
  fetchUserById,
} from '@/data_actions/userInfo_action/userInfo_action';
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {fetchUserById} from '@/data_actions/userInfo_action/userInfo_action';

const initialState = {
  isLogging: true,
  profile: null,
  isError: false,
  status: '',
  errorStatus: {},
};

export const userInfoSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userInfo',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    resetStatus(state, action) {
      state.status = '';
      state.errorStatus = {};
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchUserById.fulfilled, (state, action) => {});
  },
});
```

- component

```js
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {unwrapResult} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

function MyAccount(props) {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onClickk = async () => {
    dispatch(fetchUserById())
      .then(unwrapResult)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  };

  return (
        <button onClick={onClickk}>test</button>
  );
}
```

- store.js

```js
import {configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducer from './data_reducers/rootReducer';

const firstMiddleWare = (store) => (dispatch) => (action) => {
  dispatch(action);
};

const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: [firstMiddleWare, ...getDefaultMiddleware({serializableCheck: false})],
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});
export default store;
```

Comment: How have you configured your redux store? Are you sure you've the thunk middleware added? Can you share how you've configured your store and provided it to your app?

Comment: `fetchUserById` is not imported in your component. It would probably be best to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example to your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ksav Thanks to your advice I added more examples.

Comment: @DrewReese I added store.js code. thanks!

Comment: @GaYeonKim In your component `dispatch` is `undefined`. You have to define the `dispatch` function (before using it) by using the `useDispatch` hook like this: `const dispatch = useDispatch();`. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: @Shahid In the process of minimizing the code, even the codes that convey essential information were deleted. I'm sorry. The content has been updated, so please check.

Comment: Can you remove the `async` from the `onClickk` function as you are not using `await`. What's the output then?

Comment: @Shahid As I wrote, 'then' of undefined

Comment: Which version of `@reduxjs/toolkit` are you using?

Comment: @ksav   I'm using  "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0"

Comment: I solved it by changing `store.js` configuration. I just deleted `firstMiddleWare`, and it works fine!